# Cannot debug with Xdebug 3

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using XAMPP for PHP. I have only one php.ini file and here is my configuration:

```ini
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.mode=debug
```

`php -v` output:

```
PHP 7.4.26 (cli) (built: Nov 16 2021 18:15:31) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

In PhpStorm, the Debugger Configuration shows me this:

[image: this]

I've also installed Xdebug Extension in Chrome. But when I refresh a page with some breakpoint and with the phone button "Start listening for PHP Debug Connections" activated, the debug is not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: `php -v` isn't as helpful as first `php -m` (must contain Xdebug module) and `xdebug -i` to inspect the effective configuration. Note that CLI and webserver are separate SAPIs which are usually also configured independently!

Answer (score 3):

Please read the [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide), as some settings (such as `xdebug.remote_port` and `xdebug.remote_host`) have changed names.

To check what `xdebug.mode` is set to, use the new `xdebug_info()` function in a script that you're trying to debug, and it will give you a full overview, including whether Xdebug tried to connect to the IDE, and with which connection parameters.